# Is it possible to have two type of auth flow?

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, oauth, keycloak

Background information: The REST API will be used by a web application and server
We are thinking to have the code flow for the web application and client credential flow for the server part (machine to machine authentication). As tool, we will be using keycloak

But the problem is now that we are not sure if it is possible to have two oauth flow on one REST API.

Is it possible to have two oauth flow for one REST API?
And if it's possible, how can you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fine. In both cases the clients will perform OAuth flows using Keycloak, and these can be completely different. Your API needs to knows nothing about how clients authenticated, and in both cases receives a JWT access token.

The two different clients will not always call the same API endpoints. They are likely to use different [scopes and claims](https://curity.io/resources/learn/scopes-vs-claims/), and your API authorization design needs to deal with this. The server client will not provide a user identity via a subject claim, whereas the web app will.

The way to cope with these differences is usually to design a `ClaimsPrincipal` during JWT processing, then apply authorization rules based on the data received within the API's business logic.

In some cases, operations designed for the server client should not be callable from the web app, and vice versa. Scopes and claims will enable you to achieve this.

**EXAMPLE API**

Maybe have a look at [this code sample of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2) and the [blog post](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/13/updated-api-coding-key-points/). The key point is that the API performs these steps. If you do the same steps you will be in good shape:

- [Validates JWT access tokens](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authenticator.ts#L26)
- [Builds a claims principal](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authorizer.ts#L28)
- [Enforces scopes for each operation](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/api/src/host/controller/apiController.ts#L74)
- [Uses the claims principal to apply business authorization rules](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/api/src/logic/services/companyService.ts)

My API does some slightly advanced stuff like look up extra claims, which you can ignore. Note that the API doesn't know or care which flow clients used - there could be 5 different flows. The API's job is just to work with scopes and claims.

Comment: Do you have make a example that I can see ? That has two flow on one API

Comment: I have an interactive example above - an API with a web client. Hopefully it gets across the key points, though there is some stuff that may not be relevant to your use case.